# What is spl file?

Tags: auxiliary-files

What is the (reason of) `spl` file created when using `elsarticle` class? 
It has zero size.

[image]

Comment: `elsarticle.cls` line 644-648

Comment: @Sigur It's how the class handles extra bib options passed to `natbib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the current `elsarticle.cls`, version 3.3 released 2020-11-20 (with line numbers for reference)

```
   1210 \@ifundefined{@biboptions}{\xdef\@biboptions{numbers}}{}
   1211 \InputIfFileExists{\jobname.spl}{}{}
   1212 \ifnonatbib\relax\else
   1213   \RequirePackage[\@biboptions]{natbib}
   1214 \fi
   1215 \newwrite\splwrite
   1216 \immediate\openout\splwrite=\jobname.spl
   1217 \def\biboptions#1{\def\next{#1}\immediate\write\splwrite{%
   1218    \string\g@addto@macro\string\@biboptions{%
   1219     ,\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\next}}}
```

The `\jobname.spl` file is written, containing options for `natbib`, to be input at the next run.